# How to replace the new operator in linked list?

Tags: c++

As a new comer to c++, I am trying to learn why and where to use New.
So I am trying to NOT USE the New in this linked List example,

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct link //one element of list
{
    int data; //data item
    link* next; //pointer to next link
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class linklist //a list of links
{
private:
    link* first; //pointer to first link
public:
    linklist() //no-argument constructor
    { first = NULL; } //no first link
    void additem(int d); //add data item (one link)
    void display(); //display all links
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void linklist::additem(int d) //add data item
{
    link* newlink = new link; //make a new link
    newlink->data = d; //give it data
    newlink->next = first; //it points to next link
    first = newlink; //now first points to this
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void linklist::display() //display all links
{
    link* current = first; //set ptr to first link
    while( current != NULL ) //quit on last link
    {
        cout << current->data << endl; //print data
        current = current->next; //move to next link
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    linklist li; //make linked list
    li.additem(25); //add four items to list
    li.additem(36);
    li.additem(49);
    li.additem(64);

    return 0;
}
```

to the following:

```
 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct link //one element of list
{
    int data; //data item
    link* next; //pointer to next link
};
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class linklist //a list of links
{
private:
    link first; //pointer to first link
public:
    linklist() //no-argument constructor
    { first = NULL; } //no first link
    void additem(int d); //add data item (one link)
    void display(); //display all links
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void linklist::additem(int d) //add data item
{
    link newlink; //make a new link
    newlink.data = d; //give it data
    newlink.next = first; //it points to next link
    first = newlink; //now first points to this
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void linklist::display() //display all links
{
    link current = first; //set ptr to first link
    while( current != NULL ) //quit on last link
    {
        cout << current.data << endl; //print data
        current = current.next; //move to next link
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    linklist li; //make linked list
    li.additem(25); //add four items to list
    li.additem(36);
    li.additem(49);
    li.additem(64);
    return 0;
}
```

but this doesn't work. Before I continue trying, I am wondering if this particular example has to stick with New and cannot be done without using it.

Comment: The way not to use `new` in this example is by simply using `std::list`.

Comment: What an awful indentation... or rather lack of any form of it.

Comment: -1:  Please format your code properly.

Comment: this will not compile. first, in the line `newlink.next = first;` will throw an compiler error, you can not assign a value type to a pointer. second, you create the link object like this: `link newlink;` it is created on the stack, the object is invalid after leaving the scope of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not understand stack memory vs heap memory. What you're supposed to do is called "dynamic allocation".

If you define a variable as `link newlink;`
you create it only on the stack, meaning that when you exit your function it no longer exists, it is "deallocated". What you need for that list is to request a new area of memory that is not deallocated when you finish your function. In order to do that you need to use dynamic allocation. One of the means of doing that is the `new` operator. The other canonical way of doing is the malloc function.

TL;DR You can't do it the way you want, you seem to to have misunderstood how memory works in C\C++. You **have** to use pointers and dynamic allocation, that's why they call it a **dynamic** linked list.

Also, do not use std:list as your question and the way you write your code points to me that the linked list implementation is a homework of sorts. Learn to understand basic functionality before running to other people's implementations.

Comment: Oh got you! That's something I was missing

Answer (score 2):

A linked list can't be created without `new` or some form of dynamic memory allocation, because you can't create permanent nodes to point to on the stack.

However, luckily you don't have to write the error-prone `new` code yourself, because C++ provides you a handy `std::list` class already. Additionally is provides a singly linked `forward_list` in C++11.

Answer (score 0):

By this action

```
first = newlink;
```

you record data over the old data.

You have only one field of `linklist` class and override data at every action above.

When you use `new`, it allocates instances in the heap (outside of `linklist`) and these instances (`link`) connected with each other by pointers. In your second piece of code it doesn't take place and you have in memory only one instance of `link`.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is, essentially, a collection of individual dynamically allocated blocks, so `new`  is a requirement, whether it is exposed to client code or not.  As @Alok, suggests, a `std::list` is preferable, as it encapsulates this memory allocation and ensures no leaks occur, etc.  Your attempt to allocate `newLink` on the stack will fail compilation unless you take its address, which you certainly don't want to do (as `newLink` will be popped from the stack as soon as the function returns).

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
link newlink; //make a new link
```

you have made a link on the stack that will go out of scope by the end of the function.

I think you should use the rule "avoid raw pointers", rather than avoid new. If you use std::make_shared instead, and hold std::unique_ptr instead of raw pointers that might be a useful learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you must understand the following first:

### The stack

There are many documents that explain in depth what the stack is. But very simplified the stack memory is temporal memory that is only available within the scope in c++. By example:

```
int* p;
{
   int a; //Create a variable in stack memory
   a = 10; //Assing stack memory
   p = &a; //Create a pointer to stack memory
} //Variable a is released since the scope has ended

printf("%d",*p); //The pointer now points to released memory. Probably it will not be 10
```

The same applies for functions so:

```
void suma()
{
    int a; //This variable will only exists for this function
}
```

### Your code

What you're doing is to create and copy variables that later will be released when the functions ends.

```
link first; //pointer to first link

void linklist::additem(int d) //add data item
{
    link newlink; //I'll only exists in this function
    newlink.data = d; 
    newlink.next = first; //Does even this compiles???
    first = newlink;  //After the function sends first will point to a released memory. Aren't you missing a & operator ? &newlink
}
```

## Solution

You need to store your link nodes somewhere. New operator does that for you. But if you don't want to use it. You may store the in Static Memory.

By example you can have two static variables like this:

```
link staticLinks[100];
int lastUsedLink = 0;
```

This memory will no be releases during the whole execution of your program so you can do something like this:

```
void linklist::additem(int d) //add data item
{
    staticLinks[lastUsedLink].data = d; //Now this data will no dissapear
    lastUsedLink[lastUsedLink].next = first; //Point to the last element
    first = &lastUsedLink[lastUsedLink]; //No this becomes the last element
    lastUsedLink++; //Use the next element of the array for the next addition
}
```

It's very improvable. By example you can add a guard to avoid using 101 or more element of the array. But now you may understand the problem.

### Full code ##

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct link //one element of list
{
    int data; //data item
    link* next; //pointer to next link
};

link staticLinks[100];
int lastUsedLink = 0;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
class linklist //a list of links
{
private:
    link* first; //pointer to first link
public:
    linklist() //no-argument constructor
    { first = NULL; } //no first link
    void additem(int d); //add data item (one link)
    void display(); //display all links
};
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void linklist::additem(int d) //add data item
{
    staticLinks[lastUsedLink].data = d; //give it data
    lastUsedLink[lastUsedLink].next = first; //it points to next link
    first = &lastUsedLink[lastUsedLink]; //now first points to this
    lastUsedLink++;
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------
void linklist::display() //display all links
{
    link current = first; //set ptr to first link
    while( current != NULL ) //quit on last link
    {
        cout << current.data << endl; //print data
        current = current.next; //move to next link
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main()
{
    linklist li; //make linked list
    li.additem(25); //add four items to list
    li.additem(36);
    li.additem(49);
    li.additem(64);
    return 0;
}
```